# Characteristic polynomial of an endomorphism over 2x2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, characteristic-polynomial

I am given the endomorphism over the vector space of 2x2 matrices Mat$_2(\mathbb{R})$ defined by
$$ f(X) = \begin{pmatrix}2&2\\0&2\end{pmatrix}X.$$
I am intending to find the characteristic polynomial and the Jordan normal form of this endomorphism. But looking at the definition of the characteristic polynomial it doesn't seem like the vectorspace is important for the calculation?

Would this just be like calculating the characteristic polynomial of a 2x2 matrix or am I missing something?

Our definition of the characteristic polynomial for $A \in$ Mat$_n(\mathbb{K})$ is
$$ \chi_A(x) := \det(x \cdot I_n-A),$$

where $x \cdot I_n -A \in$ Mat$_n(\mathbb{K}[x])$. The characteristic polynomial of an endomorphism $f \in \text{End}_\mathbb{K}(V)$, where $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, is defined as
$$ \chi_f(x) = \chi_{M^B_f}(x).$$

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is independent of the choice of the basis indeed

Comment: Are you asking about choice of basis, or about the different spaces Mat$_2(\mathbb{Q})$, Mat$_2(\mathbb{R})$, Mat$_2(\mathbb{C})\,$?

Comment: @311411 I am confused as this is the first time we have an endomorphism with matrices as vectors and am thus unsure how to proceed in calculating the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Maybe you should type above your definition of the characteristic polynomial, so we can check that it looks okay.

Comment: @311411 I have edited the question.

Comment: Basic question, reality check: is $X$ for you a 2 x 1 vector, or is it a 2 x 2 matrix? After we settle that, we can decide what is $V$ in your definition. By the way you probably mean "finite-dimensional vector space", not "finite vector space".

Comment: @311411 I did yes, thanks. The task defines X to be a 2x2 matrix. Hence my confusion, because I am used to 2x1 vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our basic situation is that $f$ is a function with domain (and co-domain) Mat$_2(\mathbb{K})$, where $\mathbb{K}$ is the field of real numbers. In symbols:

$$f:\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{R}) \to \text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{R}),$$

where $f$ is left-multiplication by your fixed matrix. This map is an endomorphism of its domain, since matrix multiplication is linear.

There is some higher-level theory involved in really understanding, for example, what is the thing Mat$_n(\mathbb{K}[x])$. When $\mathbb{K}$ is any field, then $\mathbb{K}[x]$ is a polynomial ring, and so on. For finding the characteristic polynomial of your $f$, maybe you don't need to master all that stuff now.

You do need to understand $M^B_f$ though, which appears at the end of your post. This is the matrix of your linear transformation in a particular basis $B$. The comment of Evariste is demonstrated by the relation

$$ \chi_f(x) = \chi_{M^B_f}(x).$$

For we see $B$ on the right but not on the left ($\chi_f$ "is independent of the choice of the basis").

For your immediate problem, you were indeed missing something big, as follows. The $V$ you need is a *four*-dimensional vector space, because a 2 by 2 matrix has four entries. So I'd say an outline of your to-do list is

1. Write down the standard basis for your real vector space $V\,=\,\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{R})$.
2. Recall that a linear transformation (an endomorphism) of a finite-dimensional vector space can be represented by a matrix.
3. With $B$ the standard basis, figure out $M^B_f$, the matrix of your endomorphism $f$. (Will we have $M^B_f\,\in\,\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{R})\,$?)

*Note we can use the word 'vector' in two ways here. It can mean an ordinary $n$ by $1$ column of numbers, or more abstractly, it can mean any element of a given vector space. So a 2 by 2 matrix is legitimately called a vector.*

Comment: Just to make sure I got this right - M^B_f is in Mat_4, right?

Comment: You've got it right. It must be a four by four matrix. When you think you have $M^B_f$ ready, try it out on your basis matrices, and compare to what you get by using the original formula: $ f(B_1) = \begin{pmatrix}2&2\\0&2\end{pmatrix}\,\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},$ and so on.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said: "try it out on *the matrices of* your basis matrices", i.e. "try it out on the matrices of your four basis elements of $\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{R})$